# How does flex flash.net.FileReference class works

Tags: flash, apache-flex, file-upload, flex3

I have created a flex web application with php server side support. There is a file upload functionality in this website. When I'm uploading a file using flex upload controller, does it uses a huge amount of memory from the client machine that uploads the file? and how does flex controller transfer the file to server (upload the whole file at once, upload as chunks) ?

Doesn't flash.net.FileReference class allow huge file uploads (more than 4GB)?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flash.net.FileReference uses whatever network stack is available in the OS. For example, on MS Windows, this is WinInet library. So, it doesn't load the entire file into memory for transmitting it to server since WinInet doesn't require that.

That said, it doesn't do a 'chunked' upload. It does a normal HTTP multipart/form-data POST just like a browser would do if you used a HTML form containing a input type='file' HTML element.

Comment: Could you add any links to references?

Comment: Is there any trusted source for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any references, but I think I know what I am talking about. Disclosure: I am employed at Adobe, but I don't speak for my employer.